# debugging captainhook tweak

Tags: objective-c, ios, hook, jailbreak, tweak

I'm working on a tweak using captainhook.
I did something like:

```
[self.delegate somemessage];
//the message is a private api. I don't know its implementation detail.
```

and then the app used up a lot of system resources and got killed minutes later.
the problem is none of logs, errors or exceptions can be found in console. there is only a LowMemory crash report.

I'd like to know what's the possible causes of that, how can I deal with it?
I dont have even the least idea where to start to debug it…

Comment: Try tracking allocations in Instruments.

Comment: thanks. this tool seems helpful but I can't attach to Springboard when tracking allocations or leaks